# CSS Navbar item wont align right

Tags: html, css

Here is the html code in which I want login and sign up to be aligned towards the right of the navbar

```
<navbar class="navbar">
    <div class="content">
<a class="navbarbrand" href="#">Brand</a>
<div class="navbaritemcon">
    <a href="#" class="navbaritem">Home</a>
    <a href="#" class="navbaritem">About Us</a>
</div>

<div class="navbaritemcon right">
    <a href="#" class="navbaritem">Login</a>
    <a href="#" class="navbaritem">Sign Up</a>
</div>

</div>
</navbar>

</body>
```

CSS:-

Tried using float option but doesnt work either

```
.navbar{
    background-color: #17a2b8;;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    position: sticky;
    align-items: center;
}

.navbar>.content{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.content{
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 80%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;


}

.navbarbrand{
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 1rem; 
    position: relative;
}

.navbaritemcon{
    list-style: none;
    float: left;  

}

.navbaritem{
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    margin-left: 1rem;
}

.right{
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

How do I make login and signup appear aligned towards the right of the navbar. Please help not able to figure out the correct way of doing it

---

Comment: you login and sign up are inside navbaritemcon which floats left. Try changing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `margin-left:auto;` and you are good to go

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #17a2b8;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  position: sticky;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar>.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 80%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.navbarbrand {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

.navbaritemcon {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

.navbaritem {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.right {
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<navbar class="navbar">
  <div class="content">
    <a class="navbarbrand" href="#">Brand</a>
    <div class="navbaritemcon">
      <a href="#" class="navbaritem">Home</a>
      <a href="#" class="navbaritem">About Us</a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbaritemcon right">
      <a href="#" class="navbaritem">Login</a>
      <a href="#" class="navbaritem">Sign Up</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</navbar>
```

Comment: Code runs perfect can u pl explain me the logic

Comment: auto margin causes all of the available space to be rendered as whitespace, which in this case the left space of the targeted element

Answer (score 1):

```
.navbar>.content{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

<navbar class="navbar">
  <div class="content">
<div class="navbaritemcon">
  <a class="navbarbrand" href="#">Brand</a>
  <a href="#" class="navbaritem">Home</a>
  <a href="#" class="navbaritem">About Us</a>
</div>

<div class="navbaritemcon right">
  <a href="#" class="navbaritem">Login</a>
  <a href="#" class="navbaritem">Sign Up</a>
</div>

</div>
</navbar>
```

i changed html so it is easier to manipulate with css, but you can do it differently, important part is that you have parent div and 2 child divs and justify-content space-between on parent div

Answer (score 0):

I made some changed to the html and css

```
  <div class="navbaritemcon">
    <a class="navbarbrand" href="#">Brand</a>
    <a href="#" class="navbarit">Home</a>
    <a href="#" class="navbarit">About Us</a>
  </div>

  <div class="navbaritemconright">
    <a href="#" class="navbaritem">Login</a>
    <a href="#" class="navbaritem">Sign Up</a>
  </div>

  </div>
  </navbar>
```

The Css is below

```
.navbar{
    background-color: #17a2b8;;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    position: sticky;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between

}
.navbar>.content{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.content{
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 80%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;


}

.navbarbrand{
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 1rem; 
    position: relative;
}

.navbaritemcon{
    list-style: none;
    float: left;  

}

.navbaritem{
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    margin-left: 1rem;
}

.right{
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

You also need to be careful when choosing your classes.
Hope this works.